# Why can't I use only one SELECT clause with RANK() and WHERE condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, rank, column-alias

I can get the rank alias with this query:

```sql
SELECT *, 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY some_field ORDER BY value) AS rk
FROM my_table
```

Result:

| some_field | value | rk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| same | 10 | 1 |
| same | 20 | 2 |
| same | 30 | 3 |

And I tried to query with:

```sql
SELECT *, 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY some_field ORDER BY value) AS rk
FROM my_table
WHERE rk = 1
```

I got this error message
`column "rk" does not exist`

If I tried a subquery, it works :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY some_field ORDER BY value) AS rk
  FROM my_table
) AS t
WHERE rk = 1
```

Result:

| some_field | value | rk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| same | 10 | 1 |

But my question is why can't we use just one SELECT to do so.

Is it because I use a function in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. You can't use the column name in where clause. First understand, SQL execution flow. As per your sql statment, it will execute in below order.

1. From clause.
2. Apply filter where clause
3. Execute select statement.

So in your sql statment, rk column is generating at step 3. But you are accessing at step 2 which is not possible. Hope it will clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rank expression as a constraint... like so.

```
SELECT *, 
 1 AS rk
FROM my_table
WHERE  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY some_field ORDER BY value) = 1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is invalid as well.

Comment: Actually, I got an error that `window functions are not allowed in WHERE` here